# Conversion from characters [A, H, B] to numeric [1, 0, -1]

Tags: r, linux, awk, sed, cut

My goal is to convert file with 2 1 0 to file with 1 0 -1 via A H B.
For example,

```
Infile.txt        Temp.txt           Final.txt
2 2 2 1 1 1 0 0   A A A H H H B B    1 1 1 0 0 0 -1 -1
```

I was able to convert from numerics(2 1 0) to characters(A H B) using the code as follows:

```
cut -f2- Infile.txt | sed '1,1d' | sed 's/2/A/g' | sed 's/1/H/g' | sed 's/0/B/g' > Temp.txt
```

However, I could not convert from (A H B) to (1 0 -1). Hence, I got stuck with Temp.txt

So, I would appreciate any solution to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has mentioned in a comment the source file is a 20,000 x 500 (row x column) matrix of the digits `2`, `1` and `0`.

Create a 20,000 x 501 (row x column) matrix:

```
awk '
BEGIN { for (i=1;i<=20000;i++) {
            sep=""
            for (j=1;j<=167;j++) {
                printf "%s2 1 0", sep
                sep=" "
            }
            print ""
        }
      }
' > matrix.dat

$ head -5 matrix.dat | cut -c1-30
2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0
2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0
2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0
2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0
2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0
```

One `awk/gsub()` idea:

```
awk '{ gsub(/1/,9)
       gsub(/2/,1)
       gsub(/0/,-1);
       gsub(/9/,0)
     }
1
' matrix.dat > matrix.awk1.out
```

One `awk/loop` idea:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
           $i=$i-1
     }
1
' matrix.dat > matrix.awk2.out
```

One `sed` idea:

```
sed 's/1/9/g;s/2/1/g;s/0/-1/g;s/9/0/g' matrix.dat > matrix.sed.out
```

These all generate the same result:

```
$ diff matrix.awk1.out matrix.awk2.out
$ diff matrix.awk2.out matrix.sed.out
$ head -5 matrix.awk1.out | cut -c1-35
1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1
1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1
1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1
1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1
1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1 1 0 -1
```

Run times:

- system: `cygwin` (in a VM), `awk 5.1.1`, `sed 4.8`
- 5.5 secs : `awk/gsub()`
- 3.9 secs : `awk/loop`
- 5.9 secs : `sed`

Answer (score 3):

do you ***REALLY*** need the temp part ? you can do a perfect mapping between the 3 with just a tiny bit of `regex` `gsub()` :

```
echo '2 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 2 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 1 0 0 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 1 2 0 1 1 0 2 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 0 2 1' | 

mawk '{ print }

gsub(+_,__) + gsub(!_,+_) + gsub(__,"-"!_) \
                          + gsub(!_+!_,!_)^_' __='\2' | 

gtee >( gpaste - | column -t |  gsed -zE 's/^|\n/&\n/g' >&2;) |

mawk NF=NF FS='[^0-9-]+' OFS='\n' | nonEmpty | rs -t -c$'\n' 0 2 | uniqC 

2  1  1  1  0   1  2  1  1  2  0   2  0   2  1  2  1  0   1  0   0   1  2  1  0   2  2  2  2  1  0   0   2  2  0   2  0   2  0   1  2  0   1  1  0   2  0   1  1  1  0   0   2  0   0   2  1

1  0  0  0  -1  0  1  0  0  1  -1  1  -1  1  0  1  0  -1  0  -1  -1  0  1  0  -1  1  1  1  1  0  -1  -1  1  1  -1  1  -1  1  -1  0  1  -1  0  0  -1  1  -1  0  0  0  -1  -1  1  -1  -1  1  0

              19 0   -1
              19 1   0
              19 2   1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I don't need the temp file as long as I can reach the Final.txt. However, I am not familiar with mawk. So, could suggest codes in awk, sed or cut?

Comment: @user3874325 : it's just one of the 4 main variants of `awk` - the other ones being `gawk`, `nawk` (usually `macOS`), and a really bad `busybox awk`

Answer (score 2):

`tr` is a fair choice but does not like outputting the double symbol '-1'

```
 tr "012" "-01" input
```

should translates about as fast as you will with a few chars typed in a shell. you could pipe the result to a `sed`

```
sed 's/-/-1/g'
```

to expand the representation.

note:
this method operates only on the char symbol level without interpreting what they mean which would be needed to understand `-1`

Answer (score 2):

When you have to perform translations of fields from one form into another, it is easiest done using simple associative arrays (also known as translation tables, dictionaries, maps, ...). In the case of the OP, this would be done as:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ a[2]=1; a[1]=0; a[0]=-1 }
       { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i=a[$i] }
       { print }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scan` to read the numbers file, subtract `1` and write to file.

```r
{scan(text = "2 2 2 1 1 1 0 0") - 1L} |> as.character() |> writeLines("~/Temp/Final.txt")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Here is a way to read the numeric matrix, subtract 1 and write the result.

```
infile <- "~/Temp/Infile.txt"
x <- scan(infile, nlines = 1)
nc <- length(x)

x <- scan(infile) - 1L

write.table(matrix(x, ncol = nc), "~/Temp/Final.txt",
            quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

rm(x)   # final clean up
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think -1L is a nice way to go. In fact, however, I have 20000-by-500 (row-by-column) matrix to handle. In this matrix, 2, 1, and 0 are randomly positioned. Please, consider it.

Comment: @user3874325 Is the matrix all numeric with only those numbers?

Comment: Yes, the matrix is all numeric with only 2 1 0. In fact, they are SNP (single nucleotide polymorphsim in genetics) genotypes.